# Multi edge python igraph questions

Tags: python, igraph

If you have a directed multi edge weighted graph, how do you do these things?

1. For vertices I and J, list all edges from I to J.
2. Delete all edges in the graph with weight more than 10.

For 1 I can list all the outgoing edges and then filter by destination node. This seems potentially inefficient, is there some way of just getting the edges directly? For 2 I can list all the edges, look up each weight and then delete the edge if needed. Is there a neat idiomatic way of doing this?

Comment: How is the graph implemented? What data structures do you have access to? And last, but certainly not least, what have you tried (translation: welcome to SO, we're happy to help, but we're not a coding service. Show us what you've attempted (translation: we're not going to do  your home/work for you))?

Comment: The graph is read in using the read ncol method of igraph. I am using standard python plus igraph so have access to those libraries at least.

Comment: Note: This is a question about how to interact with an open-source graph library, not a question about how to implement the operations. (At first, I though the "i" was a typo.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for #1, unfortunately there is no easier solution than the one you mentioned (i.e. querying all the outgoing edges and then filtering based on the destination). The C core of igraph has a function called `igraph_get_eids_multi` which would do what you want, but there is no corresponding Python interface for the function.

As for #2, you can do this (assuming that `g` is your graph object, `weight` is the name of the edge attribute holding the weights, and `gt` stands for "greater than"):

```
g.es.select(weight_gt=10).delete()
```

where `g.es` represents the edge sequence of the whole graph, and its `select` method subsets the edge sequence based on some criteria (see the documentation of [`EdgeSeq.select`](http://pythonhosted.org/python-igraph/igraph.EdgeSeq-class.html#select) for more details), returning another `EdgeSeq`. The `delete()` method of the filtered edge sequence then deletes the edges.

Comment: I realize I can't get #1 to work either.  If I list all outgoing edges from I then I don't know how to get it as a list of tuples so I can filter by the end vertex J.

Comment: `[edge for edge in g.es[g.incident(source)] if edge.target == target]` should do the trick. You can also use `[edge.index for edge...` if you need the edge index only.